# API request error - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks

i tried fetching an API request but it is getting back this error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.deezer.com/chart' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

the code

```
const {data, setData} = useState({});
    const API = "https://api.deezer.com/chart";
    useEffect(() => {
        axios(API)
        .then(response => {
            setData(response);
            console.log(data)

        })
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe this is the same question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to understand that the CORS behavior is not an error — it’s a mechanism that’s working as expected in order to protect your users, you, or the site you’re calling. [Check Link here](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b)

You can make it work by following different ways :

**Temporary solution :**

1. Disabling chrome security using

   Windows : Windows + R --> chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir

   MacOS : open -na Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/temporary-chrome-profile-dir --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials
2. Adding and using chrome extension :
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc/related?hl=en-GB

**Permanent Solution :**

If you don't have access to the api server which i can see you don't have you can call this API from your wrapper server it can be any server for eg : Node-express server or Java server (Adding basic node server example just call /getCharts api and you will get your desired results)

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const axios = require('axios');

app.get('/getCharts', (req, res) => {
  const API = "https://api.deezer.com/chart";
  axios(API)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data)
      res.json(response.data)
    }).catch(err => {
      res.send('errr!!!')
    })
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const url = "https://api.deezer.com/chart";
const config = {
   url,
   headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
    }
}


const {data, setData} = useState({});
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios(config)
        .then(response => {
            setData(response);
            console.log(data)

        })
   }  //closing bracket required
); //closing bracket required
```

you need to send your headers like this. Or you can set axios global default header [axios default header](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults)

and in you API side you need to activate CORS

```
// if it is node api
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the mode to 'no-cors' for this api to work :

```
fetch("https://api.deezer.com/chart", {
  mode: 'no-cors'
});
```